# How exactly would one override a CssResource

Tags: gwt, cssresource

Currently I have an application using CssResource in gwt like this...

```
interface MyClientBundle extends ClientBundle{

@Source("images/one.png")
Image someImageThatAlwaysLooksTheSame();

@Source("images/two.png")
Image someImageThatDependingOnTheClientThemeChanges();

@Source("css/main.css")
MyCssResource css();

}
```

And then the CssResource interface

```
interface MyCssResource extends CssResource{

String someStyleThatNeverChanges();

String someStyleThatChangesDependingOnTheClient();

}
```

If I override MyClientBundle to create and interface called MyPinkThemedClientBundle

```
interface MyClientBundle extends ClientBundle{

@Source("images/one.png")
Image someImageThatAlwaysLooksTheSame();

@Source("images/**twoPinkVersion**.png")
Image someImageThatDependingOnTheClientThemeChanges();

@Source("css/**mainPinkVersion**.css")
MyPinkCssResource css();

}
```

Then of course MyPinkCssResource extends MyCssResource

```
interface MyPinkCssResource extends MyCssResource{


}
```

The problem I have is that when I try to compile this the GWT compiler complains that "css/mainPinkVersion.css" is missing the style name "someStyleThatNeverChanges".  I would have thought that a cssresource interface would inherit the backing css file of its super class.  If this is not the case, is it possible to achieve the effect of being able to extend a CssResource and override just the classes you care about but otherwise use the super-classes' backing .css file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into almost exactly this issue. The solution I came up with after reading [the @Import example in the GWT documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Example_StackPanel) is as follows. In your  `MyPinkThemedClientBundle` you need to define css() method as:

```
@Source({"main.css", "css/**mainPinkVersion**.css"})
MyCssResource css();
```

If you are just overriding already defined CSS entries, and not creating any new ones that need to be accessed in your code then you won't need the MyPinkCssResource type.

Comment: I get "error: annotation Source is missing value for the attribute value" when I try have 2 comma separated css files.  Tried GWT 2.5.1 and 2.6.0.  Actually this comes from the Java compiler under Netbeans, not GWT compiler.  Did you have the same issues?

Comment: Putting values in braces (since the annotation is defined as String []) like @Source({"main.css", "myPinkVersion.css"}) gets rid of java compiler error.  I'm not sure how you guys are compiling it on your system and not getting these errors.